# Call to a phone number through iPhone App

Tags: ios4

Hi iPhone developers, I want to add a feature in my iPhone app, they are:
call to a phone number in my app
after call end, relaunch the previous app. 
I know its not possible in iphone OS 3.2..
Is it possible in iOS 4?
I need your help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call a number *directly* from your app. You can use this snippet to launch the phone app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12125551212"]];
```

... and after the call is done it will return you to your app.